# Merge PowerPoint files Using PowerShell and PowerPoint application object

Tags: powershell, merge, powerpoint, object-model

I need a simple PowerShell script to merge n number of pptx files into a single pptx file.  Seems like MergeWithBaseline off the presentation object should work, but I continue to get an error.

Add-type -AssemblyName office
add-type -assembly microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint

$strwithPresentation = ".\one.pptx"
$strbaselinePresentation = ".\two.pptx"

$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application

$presentation = $application.Presentations.add()

$presentation.MergeWithBaseline($strwithPresentation, $presentation.FullName)

I have tried many options but continue to get this error:

PS C:\Users\ltsharpe\Documents\scripts> C:\Users\ltsharpe\Documents\scripts\MergePPTX.ps1
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
At C:\Users\ltsharpe\Documents\scripts\MergePPTX.ps1:10 char:1

- $presentation.MergeWithBaseline($strwithPresentation, $presentation.F ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

What is the best way to programmatically merge pptx files into a single one?  Few hits on searches and most are 10+ years old.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated as I do not want to cut/paste 20+ pptx files into one on a monthly basis :(.

Comment: This article provides a solution to merging PowerPoint files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267055/how-do-i-modify-this-script-to-take-parameters Many thanks to a friend that found this and passed it on :)

Comment: This is the actual answer for the question, it definitely deserves to be published as one. Thank you for sharing!